# Extendend desktop using HDMI to DVIx2 splitter

Tags: windows-7

My laptop has one HDMI output + 1 VGA.
But my monitors x2 are VGA/DVI.

I bought a HDMI to DVIx2 splitter to connect both my monitors. 
However the inbuilt (laptop) display is used as screen one and both the external monitors as extendend desktop.
How can i avoid using the laptop and use only the external monitors as screen 1 & 2 without duplicating the screens?
Laptop seems to be sending the same signal to both the monitors because of the splitter. 
Is there a way to fix this ?

My laptop is a acer aspire 7750 running windows 7. 
Thanks,
Sud

Comment: Welcome to superuser.  Please edit your question to include the make & model of your laptop.

Comment: Done. Its Acer Aspire 7750 running windows 7, i5 & intel graphic card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your screen settings. You can access Windows' screen settings by right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Screen resolution", or typing "adjust screen resolution" in the Start menu search box. Click the "Identify" button to throw up numbers on each screen to identify them and then drag and drop them to match your current arrangement.

Check the checkbox "Make this my main display" on one of your external monitors you want to be your main display. Your other monitor should have "Extend desktop to this display" selected in the "Multiple displays" drop down menu. Then select "Disconnect this display" on your laptop screen.

The splitter you have sounds like it has a male HDMI to 2x female DVI splitter.Those types of splitters will only allow you to extend the display, but both will show the same display. You need to purchase a [HDMI to VGA adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O55U8K) to connect to first external monitor (laptop HDMI > adapter HDMI > adapter VGA > monitor VGA). You can plug in the VGA cable to connect the second external monitor (laptop VGA > monitor VGA).